# Set checkbox "checked" using jstl

Tags: jsp, checkbox, foreach, jstl

The following is a snippet of the jstl to set and display a series of checkboxes:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${sessionAnswerObjects}">
    <c:set var="item1" value="${fn:split(item, vertBar)}"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="eList" name="sessionSubEntityAnswer" value="${item1[0]}${vertBar}${item1[1]}${vertBar}${item1[2]}${vertBar}${item1[3]}${vertBar}${item1[4]}${vertBar}${item1[5]}" ${item1[4]=='I hate the food'?'checked':''}/> 
    <c:out value="${item1[4]}"></c:out>
    <br>
 </c:forEach>
```

The "c:out" statement displays the particular variable but the checkbox is not "checked" as given in the input statement.

The output of the jsp is, in part:

```
    How do you like the food?
        [] I Like the food
        [] I don't like the food
        [] I really, really don't like the food
        [] I hate the food
```

Any assistance with the jstl given above is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Roy W.

Comment: What are you doing in `value` attribute of `checkbox` input?

Comment: hi Braj:  Firstly, thanks for your prompt reply.  In the input type statement, I need to pass the delimited string to the Java bean.  It seems, though, that when a array is used with a specific array occurrence in the input type statement, the "checked" property is not set.  If possible, can you test passing a delimited string by value and set a specific occurrence of the string to "checked."

Answer (score 0):

I went through inumerable test iteractions of the code seqment above, but eureka, I finally determined the cause of the "checked" checkbox bug.  In the above initial code segment, the variable "vertBar" is the unicode character, "\u00A6", followed by a space or "\u00A6 ".  This character "\u00A6" is defined as a broken vertical bar, not as the variable, vertBar (vertical bar) implies.

The problem lies in the space after the delimiter.  The split function fails to set "checked" for the checkbox if a space exists after a delimited string that is defined as a special unicode character.  Once I removed the space after the unicode delimiter, the split function worked.

I hope this helps someone.

Roy W.